# node express find() entries by createdAt attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to fetch mongo document entries between a date range by using the createdAt attribute.

This is what I've tried so far with no luck

JSON body I'm sending across in the request body

```
{"startDate":"2020-01-06",
"endDate":"2020-01-07"}
```

Code snippet

```
    var startDate = req.body.startDate+" 00:00:00.000";    
    var endDate = req.body.endDate+" 23:59:59.000";  

    registerEmpModel.
        find({
            createdAt: {
                $gte: startDate,
                $lte: endDate
            }
        })
        .exec(function (err, data) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            res.send(data);
        });
```

Mongo document structure

```
    {
        "_id": "5dea70cf21b47e11289f3e6e",
        "registerEmpID":ObjectId("5dea70cf21b47e11289f3e6d"),
        "registerType": "TEST",
        "registerItemsQuantity": 1,
        "registerItemsDesc": "testing",
        "createdAt": "2019-12-06T15:16:31.969Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-12-06T15:16:31.969Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. You need to create a new Date before compare

```
var startDate = req.body.startDate+"T00:00:00.000Z";    
var endDate = req.body.endDate+"T23:59:59.000Z";

registerEmpModel.
        find({
            createdAt: {
                $gte: new Date(startDate).toISOString(),
                $lte: new Date(endDate).toISOString()
            }
        })
        .exec(function (err, data) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            res.send(data);
        });
```

or use `ISODate(startDate)` and `ISODate(endDate)`

https://www.compose.com/articles/understanding-dates-in-compose-mongodb/

Comment: Tried your code as-is and with ISODate both didnt get me a response. Also ISODate in express comes as undefined.

Comment: change res.send to console.log() to check. res.send may not work inside async

Comment: weird thing, in mongo compass filter this works

{createdAt: {$gte: ISODate('2020-01-06T00:00:00.000Z'),$lt: ISODate('2020-01-07T23:59:00.000Z')}}

but from express in find() im getting back no data/ empty []

Comment: Hey, this worked

var startDate = new Date(req.body.startDate).toISOString();    
    var endDate = new Date(req.body.endDate).toISOString();